# Migrate Spring MVC to Spring boot 2.2.6 - tiles configuration is not loaded

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp, apache-tiles

I have migrated Spring MVC 5.2.5 to Spring Boot 2.2.6.
The project has many JSP pages and uses Apache tiles in order to build the templates.

> The Spring application class looks like:

[image]

> The Pom.xml dependecies are:

```
<artifactId>test</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.35</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate5</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

> The WebConfiguration class:

```
   @Configuration
   @EnableWebMvc
   @EnableAspectJAutoProxy
   @Slf4j
   @EnableSwagger2
   public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer
  {
    @Autowired
    private CommonConstants commonConstants;

    @Autowired
    private RestInterceptor restInterceptor;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    
    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void configureAsyncSupport(AsyncSupportConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.setDefaultTimeout(120*1000L);
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        ResourceHandlerRegistration handler = registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**");
        try {
            if (StringUtils.hasText(commonConstants.getBflowResourceDir())) {
                for (String location 
         Arrays.asList(StringUtils.split(commonConstants.getBflowResourceDir(), ","))) {
                    log.info("Using custom directory for resources: " + location);
                    handler.addResourceLocations("file:" + location + "/");
                }
            }

            handler.addResourceLocations("/dist/");
            }
        catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("error", e);
        }

        handler.addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/dist/");
    }

    @Bean
    public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer() {
        TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer = new TilesConfigurer();

        String[] definitions = new String[] {"WEB-INF/tiles.xml"};
        tilesConfigurer.setDefinitions(definitions);
        tilesConfigurer.setCheckRefresh(true);

        return tilesConfigurer;
    }

    @Bean
    public TilesViewResolver tilesViewResolver() {
        TilesViewResolver tilesViewResolver = new TilesViewResolver();
        tilesViewResolver.setOrder(-1);
        return tilesViewResolver;
    }
}
```

> The tiles configuration file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"
        "tiles-config_3_0.dtd">

<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="simple_template" template="/WEB-INF/templates/simple_template.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="global" value="/WEB-INF/views/general/global.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="main_template" extends="simple_template">
        <put-attribute name="body">
            <definition template="/WEB-INF/templates/main_template.jsp">
                <put-attribute name="header_include" value="/WEB-INF/views/general/header_include.jsp" />
                <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/views/modules/header.jsp" />
            </definition>
        </put-attribute>
    </definition>

    <definition name="content_template" extends="main_template">
        <put-attribute name="main_body" cascade="true">
            <definition template="/WEB-INF/templates/content_template.jsp" />
        </put-attribute>
    </definition>

    <definition name="login" extends="content_template">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="login.title" cascade="true" />
        <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/views/login/login.jsp" cascade="true" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="home" extends="main_template">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="home.title" cascade="true" />
        <put-attribute name="main_body" value="/WEB-INF/dist/ng2/index-ng2.jsp" cascade="true" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="single_page_message/*" extends="content_template">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="{1}" cascade="true" />
        <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/views/general/single_page_message.jsp" cascade="true" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="access_error" extends="simple_template">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/general/single_page_message.jsp" type="template" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="standalone/**" extends="simple_template">
        <put-attribute name="inner" value="{1}" cascade="true" />
        <put-attribute name="title" value="{1}" cascade="true" />
        <put-attribute name="body">
            <definition template="/WEB-INF/templates/standalone_template.jsp">
                <put-attribute name="header_include" value="/WEB-INF/views/general/header_include.jsp" />
            </definition>
        </put-attribute>
    </definition>

    <definition name="**.jsp" template="{1}.jsp" />

    <definition name="**" extends="simple_template">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/{1}.jsp" type="template" />
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

The server is started succeussfully and I am getting views from JSP pages.
Yet, the tiles configuration has not loaded the page are without header and footer.

What am I missing?

Thanks for all the help